# Dificuldade com Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Tenho o seguinte conteúdo em uma `string`:

> |1300|11349|03042016|10857,000|0,000|10857,000|444,470|10412,530|25,530|0,000|10387,000|
>   |1310|8|4657,000|0,000|4657,000|444,470|4212,530|5,530|0,000|4207,000|
>   |1320|25||||||281647,640|281203,170|0,000|444,470|
>   |1320|26||||||308202,420|308202,420|0,000|0,000|
>   |1310|11|6200,000|0,000|6200,000|0,000|6200,000|20,000|0,000|6180,000|
>   |1320|28||||||439837,300|439837,300|0,000|0,000|
>   |1300|11518|03042016|8057,000|0,000|8057,000|560,519|7496,481|0,000|25,519|7522,000|
>   |1310|7|8057,000|0,000|8057,000|560,519|7496,481|0,000|25,519|7522,000|
>   |1320|13||||||420207,150|420146,581|0,000|60,569|
>   |1320|14||||||457108,130|456806,946|0,000|301,184|
>   |1320|21||||||460614,020|460518,267|0,000|95,753|
>   |1320|22||||||544902,750|544799,677|0,000|103,073|

Eu gostaria de quebrar essa string em um `array` para os blocos que começam com **|1300|**

Eu ficaria com um ***vetor de duas posições***, dessa forma cada posição do vetor por exemplo:

**Posição 1:**

> |1300|11349|03042016|10857,000|0,000|10857,000|444,470|10412,530|25,530|0,000|10387,000|
>   |1310|8|4657,000|0,000|4657,000|444,470|4212,530|5,530|0,000|4207,000|
>   |1320|25||||||281647,640|281203,170|0,000|444,470|
>   |1320|26||||||308202,420|308202,420|0,000|0,000|
>   |1310|11|6200,000|0,000|6200,000|0,000|6200,000|20,000|0,000|6180,000|
>   |1320|28||||||439837,300|439837,300|0,000|0,000|

**Posição 2**

> |1300|11518|03042016|8057,000|0,000|8057,000|560,519|7496,481|0,000|25,519|7522,000|
>   |1310|7|8057,000|0,000|8057,000|560,519|7496,481|0,000|25,519|7522,000|
>   |1320|13||||||420207,150|420146,581|0,000|60,569|
>   |1320|14||||||457108,130|456806,946|0,000|301,184|
>   |1320|21||||||460614,020|460518,267|0,000|95,753|
>   |1320|22||||||544902,750|544799,677|0,000|103,073|

***Eu tentei o código abaixo, mas não funcionou***

```
string[] arr1300 = Regex.Split(conteudo, @"(\|1300\|)");
```

Comment: [Conhece isso aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/)?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez conhecia não. Dei uma olhada no pacote. parece ter bastante coisa. obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que um `Split` normal resolve o seu problema:

```
string stringSplit = "|1300|";
string[] arr1300 = conteudo.Split(new string[] { stringSplit }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Após o `Split` basta concatenar o "`|1300|`" para que as posições fiquem igual você quer:

```
string posicao1 = stringSplit + arr1300[0];
string posicao2 = stringSplit + arr1300[1];
```

Se tiver mais de duas posições pode concatenar o "`|1300|`" em todas posições de uma vez:

```
arr1300 = arr1300.Select(x => stringSplit + x).ToArray();
```

Comment: Acho que ele pediu usando regex.

Comment: Vou tentar. Na verdade eu tinha tentado com Split, porém o |1300| era removido, e não queria fazer um for para colocar ele novamente; acho que a última sugestão de código vai resolver.

Comment: Deu certo, embora o split removesse uma parte do conteúdo, a última instrução que faz o Select concatenando o delimitador atendeu perfeitamente e com poucas linhas.